# How to access XSDocument element?

Tags: .net, parsing, xsd

I have the following XSD file and i cannot obtain the inner element with the name "document":

I have tried so far the following to no avail:

```
XDocument doc=Xdocument.Load([path]);
XNamespace ns="https://fr7.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml";
```

------------------------------------- All these i have tried: --------------------------------

```
var children=doc.Elements().Elements(); //here i get the immediate children, but cant filter 

var documentNode=children.Where(x=>x.Attribute("name").Value=="document").First();

var documentNode=children.Element("document");

var documentNode=children.Element(ns+"document");
```

**XML File**

```
<!--This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml" targetNamespace="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <link type="text/css" id="dark-mode" rel="stylesheet" href=""/>
  <style type="text/css" id="dark-mode-custom-style"/>
  <xs:annotation></xs:annotation> 
  <xs:element name="document"><xs:element>   ----how do i get this one
  <xs:complexType name="something"></xs:complexType>
</xs:schmea>
```

I do not know how to access specific elements in this schema and how does the namespace fit in.I have tried adding to all names the namespace to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-queries-linq-to-xml

The first link on this page is 'How to find an element with a specific attribute (C#)' which seems to be exactly your problem.